# Ubuntu 12.04 and 5GHz throughput

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I'm running an Asus G73 laptop with an Intel 6200N wireless adapter hooked to a Netgear WNDR3700 router and Netgear CMD31T cable modem. My throughput is all over the place. It will drop to 48 Mb/s, jump up to 130 Mb/s and on a good day will hit 180 to 270 for a few seconds. It's always running at 130 or lower though most of the time, enough though I have everything obvious set for 5GHz and not 2.4GHz. Naturally, when I go into Windows it runs full bore all the time as I do a lot of streaming.

Is there something I can tweak to get it up to 300 Mb/s or do I maybe have a bad component? I've only been running Ubuntu for a few months, but I am tech-savvy enough to poke around all of the obvious places. I just don't know enough about the sub-system yet to dig into there?

---

#### Device information

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(network|wireless)"
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 [8086:422c] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 2x2 AGN [8086:1301]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

#### Kernel

```
uname -r
3.2.0-36-generic
```

#### Firmware packages

```
apt-cache policy linux-firmware\*    
linux-firmware-nonfree:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.11ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.11ubuntu1 0 "Link snipped" archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     1.11 0 "Link snipped" archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
linux-firmware:
  Installed: 1.79.1
  Candidate: 1.79.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.79.1 0 "Link snipped" archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.79 0 "Link snipped" archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

<sup>For the "Link snipped" markers I had to erase the "500 http://" part because I don't have enough reputation yet to post links.</sup>

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you provide some more information? Please post the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(network|wireless)"`, `uname -r` and `apt-cache policy linux-firmware\*`. Please *edit* your question with this information.

Comment: I've done some testing on my Intel Ultimate-N 6300 (similar to yours) and a TP-Link TL-WDR4300 [running OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wdr4300) using 450Mbps on 5GHz (40 MHz band). Running several newer kernels gave me very different results. Some 3.5 seem to run stable, but ~90 Mbps and some 3.7 kernels gave me a more instable connection, but 110+ Mbps peak speeds... (I can't test the regular 3.2 Ubuntu kernel with 12.04 as other hardware won't run well on my machine). Can you try installing Quantal's kernel? (`linux-generic-lts-quantal` in Precise)

Comment: This information is already in your question... Why do you post it again as comments a few days later? Unless there's new information in it, you can remove them. And if there is new information in it, just update the question. :)

Comment: Sorry, I changed kernals and thought you'd want to see the update status?

Comment: Ah I must have missed that part... just **edit** your question with your attempts and results like this one.

Comment: I updated the kernel to 3.5.0.22.29 and I'm getting a bit better numbers. It's staying in the 240 to 270 Mbps range a lot more, but then drops back to 130 for awhile. Darn, looked just now and it was at 40. Oh well?

Comment: After reviewing the 2 sets of data, nothing was different except for the version number. Everything else was identical.